# Why does Apple Clang make a call to compare for a unique hash in an unordered map?

Tags: c++, clang, libc++

I was trying to improve my understanding of the implementation of `unordered_map`
and was surprised by this behavior. Consider this minimal example below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

template<>
struct std::hash<int*>
{
    size_t operator()(int* arr) const
    {
        cout << "custom hash called" << endl;
        return arr[0];
    }
    
};


template <>
struct std::equal_to<int*>
{
    bool operator()(const int* lhs, const int* rhs) const
    {
        std::cout << "call to compare" << std::endl;
        return lhs == rhs;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
    int arr1[8] {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18};
    int arr2[8] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    
    unordered_map<int*, string> myMap;
    myMap.insert(make_pair(arr1, "one"));
    myMap.insert({arr2, "two"});
}
```

I would have expected this output:

```
custom hash called
custom hash called
```

The hash for both inserts is unique and therefore no comparison of multiple keys should be required as I understand it (since the bucket should only contain exactly one key). And indeed this is the result when I try it with Clang, GCC and MSVC on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/Pa77d9Pb9). However, when I compile and run this example on a local Mac an additional call to the equal_to call operator happens for the second insert:

```
custom hash called
custom hash called
call to compare
```

Tested with

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

and

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

In all cases only the C++20 flag was used.

Comment: It seems to be an implementation issue related to libc++: https://godbolt.org/z/3xb5qhW7q. BTW, IIRC, specialization of `std` class tempaltes for non-custom types is not allowed.

Comment: My guess: the comparator does not need to be called only in case of equal hashes. It may need to be called also when those hasehes are mapped to the same bucket. With libc++, after insertion of the first element, the number of buckets is only 2 and the second element seems to target the same bucket: https://godbolt.org/z/3xKcxT5Kn.

Comment: thanks, that the values fall in the same bucket was also my suspicion and I did also print the bucket count, but didn't think of printing the bucket size. I assumed the unique hash would automatically result in a unique bucket.

Comment: There is one additional issue. Even with the same bucket, when the hashes are different, the comparator does not need to be called if the hashes are cached. libstdc++ seems to support such caching (controlled by some traits mechanism; see https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/hashtable.h#L209). In the source code of libc++, I cannot find caching to be implemented.

Comment: is it an error that two different hashes fall into the same bucket? I always thought that only identical hashes should fall into the same bucket.

Comment: It really seems that the problem is related to caching of hash values. Libstdc++ seems to apply it, while libc++ does not: https://godbolt.org/z/er9qWjvbY. In both cases, two elements ended up in the same bucket.

Comment: _"is it an error that two different hashes fall into the same bucket?"_ Of course not. Hashes are values typically from the whole range of the corresponding data type (64bit integer). But buckets are only very "few" in this perspective. You need to map hashes to bucket indexes (such as with modulo operation). Load factor cares about average numbers: https://godbolt.org/z/K4f3no8fd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two cases where the comparator does not need to be applied:

1. The first one is when the **target bucket is empty** (then, there is nothing to compare with). A simple demo code that works with both libstdc++ and libc++ is as follows:

```
struct Hash {
  size_t operator()(int a) const { return a; }
};

struct Equal { ...  /* log operator call */ };

std::unordered_map<int, int, Hash, Equal> m; 
m.reserve(2);

std::cout << m.bucket(0) << std::endl;  // 0
std::cout << m.bucket(1) << std::endl;  // 1

m.insert({0, 0});
m.insert({1, 0})
```

Here, both keys 0 and 1 target different buckets, so there is no comparison with both implementations.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/5jfYv6sba

2. The second case is when all the keys in the target bucket have different hashes and those **hashes are stored (cached) in the hash table nodes**. This caching is supported by libstdc++ and seems to be applied by default. However, it does not seem to be supported by libc++. Exemplary code:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int, Hash, Equal> m; 
m.reserve(2);

std::cout << m.bucket(0) << std::endl;  // 0
std::cout << m.bucket(2) << std::endl;  // 0

m.insert({0, 0});
m.insert({2, 0})
```

Here, both keys target the same bucket (with index 0). With libstdc++, since the hashes are cached and are different, they are compared and there is no reason to additionally compare the entire keys. However, with libc++, hashes are not cached and the keys need to be compared.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/vWK4Ko7Yj